# Java HashMap to a C# Dictionary

Tags: java, c#, dictionary, hashmap

I was using `HashMap` in **Java**, like this:

```
Map<Player, List<Attribute>> map = new HashMap<>();

map.put(
  player("Lebron James"), 
  attribute("mid height", "mid weidght", "high vertical")
);
```

It works perfectly, but now I wanted to *convert* it into **C#**, using `Dictionary`:

```
Dictionary<Player, List<Attribute>> dictionary = new Dictionary<Player, List<Attribute>>();

dictionary.Add(
  player("Kobe Bryant"), // <- Doesn't compile
  attribute("mid height", "mid weidght", "high vertical")
);
```

Can someone explain me, why **C#** code *doesn't compile* ? The message is

> A player component that cannot be called cannot be used as a method

Comment: Can you explicitly tell us what's *not working* and how the result looks? Is there an error (message)?

Comment: `dictionary.Add` of a `Dictionary<Player, List<Attribute>>` expects a `List<Attribute>` as second parameter, but you only pass a single `Attribute` instead of a list. And this is exactly what the compiler error message (that you forgot to include in your question) tells you.

Comment: "A player component that cannot be called cannot be used as a method"

Comment: `new Player("Kobe Bryant")` instead of `player("Kobe Bryant")`?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, yup that works, thank you! Now I need to solve attribute problem with list, because "there is no constructor which has 3 parameters"..

Comment: Your Java code shouldn't work either without the `new `!.. If that Java code is indeed working, it would mean you have methods called `player` and `attribute` which return a `Player` instance and `List<Attribute>` respectively, which could be done in the C# .NET code as well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FYI: The accepted answer using `new` is NOT a port of the provided Java answer. The end result may be the same (and I actually recommend using new instances instead of the methods called `player` and `attribute`), but it's not a port of the Java answer. I primarily wanted to clarify that in this answer in case someone else comes across this SO question & answer in the future.**

Based on the Java code, it seems your program should contain the ***methods*** `player(String)` and `attribute(String, String, String)`, which return a `Player`-instance and `List<Attribute>`-instance respectively. So you should create those same methods in the C# .NET program.

Your current Java snippet doesn't work as is, and actually would result in a similar error! [**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##jU9Na4QwEL37K4acTLH@AbdCb6XsQqHH0sO4hjVu1JCMLqXsb7ejYz310EMS3ryPvGlxwse2vs6z7fwQCFoe5CNZlz8UydlhjHBC238nAILeHH6ZsGCAdwq2v0CkUKxYuPR3rEUFiwCeIIronsiRuGdicTWS@Ttxp/8VypcfK2fPTCLxMw22ho77b/aPT8At4IT@IH0zONpIh/2rsmSL5@ze3OAFY7NIy1QXyWpkLvcjpVLDy8rqaKow9PCKnYlKZyAs7vVVx00aYy8NqQxWdDO23mDDc5hM4M7olF7MulhXus/zDw)

The accepted answer using the `new` to create new instances of the `Player` and `List<Attribute>` directly may work and give the same results in both programs, but it's ***not a direct port*** of your current Java implementation! Otherwise your Java code would have looked like this instead:

```java
Map<Player, List<Attribute>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(
  new Player("Lebron James"), 
  new ArrayList<Attribute>(){{
    add(new Attribute("mid height"));
    add(new Attribute("mid weidght"));
    add(new Attribute("high vertical"));
  }}
);
```

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##jZDdaoNAEIXvfYrBKy2pL5BUyF0pKRR6WXoxxkXX@rPMjoZQfHY7uquEUkou/Jk5356ZPRUO@FjlX9OkG9MRQyWNpGddJw/74FyjtfCKuv0OAFz1VuNV0VwDvDPptgDLtF9qp0VrO3YUzAA8gXXQGLjH2R1Z4Kxn9bfjJt9lKi/TZ7U@i4gsn6HTOTSyvz/@8QnoDeZbgaGuIGzEp1WXpRXFztAriRgRu6bzJz0gK@fsxdXQHFwAOzhpy4dt9zSVHYwf8oy2nNF0nSRSYnqO/LVmxucYnlRGXQsv2Cgbxju4QY5EeP01RjZZwwHAPI8WcEswbGTlUumi5DD2w/8hL0rnd6Cl@MGgSOLG@gYex@XHJzdO0w8)

Assuming your more complete Java code is something like this:

```java
  ...

  Map<Player, List<Attribute>> map = new HashMap<>();
  map.put(
    player("Lebron James"), 
    attribute("mid height", "mid weidght", "high vertical")
  );
}

private Player player(String name){
  return new Player(name);
}

private List<Attribute> attribute(String... strAttributes){
  List<Attribute> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
  for(String strAttr : strAttributes){
    resultList.add(new Attribute(strAttr));
  }
  return resultList;
}
```

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##bZLPbsIwDMbvPIXVUzuxPMBgSLtNE5Mm7TjtYGgGYf0nJy1CE8/euXEaOtihVLE///J9Lgfs8P6Qf/e9KZuaHBy4oFpnCnW3mG0LtBZe0VQ/MwA5vRV40jScAd4dmWoHFZZ64QvSTMd6JjLwCniESlTnmTwCfHKs3rRO/2EiV0Ud@yMWI3YQMRanWP5p2k1htmAdOn51tcmh5Axh/uMzEoZk0FC9IywHe/roS2kmwNBRDCInReGT6dBpIYfmCGyWsoM5rI11y2h@tWIPTbjkGe1@kK7Gm7ilmtalIVcja0zWekN1BS@8PZtkc5jElo0kJTvYa7Pbu2QO/nTUJg/HPdeh08RbwCLJ/PRtCvE73jn5pCETaddS5X2Hz@ubN5yrvBOXwlRK8bIoKmzgX8@Rtm3hhmrY1hMRnrwq7uurjk4DEh7@hcMEpzDPUw@MzsJIll3@QTHwZVCinvv@Fw)

The ported C# .NET code would become this:

```cs
  ...

  IDictionary<Player, IList<Attribute>> dictionary = new Dictionary<Player, IList<Attribute>>();
  dictionary.Add(
    player("Lebron James"), 
    attribute("mid height", "mid weidght", "high vertical")
  );
}

private Player player(string name){
  return new Player(name);
}

private IList<Attribute> attribute(params string[] strAttributes){
  IList<Attribute> resultList = new List<Attribute>();
  foreach(string strAttr in strAttributes){
    resultList.Add(new Attribute(strAttr));
  }
  return resultList;
}
```

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##jVNNa4NAED3XXzF4Ukj9A0kDoYXSEqGQY@lhotO4sK6yuyaEkt9ud93VrEkPPYjOx3tv5jEW6rFoJPV9p5g4wO6sNNXLKIyy54ZzKjRrhMpeSZBkxTJquz1nBRQclYL8JwKYZT44nkna9FRQWlpSgTUtw7xrTcZy6kAwNMITCNd8idwzU9loA9p3mv4SQlOcCU3doxZOWrbXaGGo9RAFjKjN69iwEnJkIvHAHFrZHCTWdk46QZ6kXtGls51GqV3yElk@yY6oyTH5oqN6YYPDKM8rZ8gC3rZM6dU09XoN5dTkBf@DGme6grNNWSZ@89a5H29pLxsB78Z0FacLCIxxnsW1Gbkidqh0vIAhOhErfViZPBxJGpuQx@mAvl/bzThqBgfhTZCkOymGzfxVDMU7ntsdgzFbNL4rfwOfX/Zj6lNe5g4uSXVc26z39aZhtPDb/CpYVOPknhuY@FMGAt7Bcss8O0IbpOn16CYHrkC3@6XvfwE)

Again, I primarily created this answer for other people coming across this question & answer in the future, and to clarify that the accepted answer is not a direct port of the provided Java snippet.

Comment: Not to be too picky, but an even more accurate conversion would be to declare 'map' as an interface, like the original code: IDictionary<Player, List<Attribute>> dictionary = new Dictionary<Player, List<Attribute>>();

Comment: @DaveDoknjas You're completely right, fixed. Same also applies to the `List`/`ArrayList` vs `IList`/`List`. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 1):

You, probably, want to *create instances* - a `Player` and `List<Attribute>` with its items.

```
dictionary.Add(
  new Player("Kobe Bryant"), 
  new List<Attribute>() {
    new Attribute("mid height"), 
    new Attribute("mid weidght"), 
    new Attribute("high vertical"),
  }
);
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought that conversion to C# from Java will be easier.

Comment: That's not an accurate conversion - you're taking a wild guess.  More importantly, it seems that the 'player' and 'attribute' methods are missing - dealing with that is the core issue.